# Close window from command line (on windows)

Tags: windows, command-line

Is it possible to send a close command to an application from command line? I know that I can kill the process, but it seems a bit heavy handed. If not from command line, another suggestion?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use taskkill (without the option -f) for that purpose.

Comment: I notice from a Google search that there is both a taskkill and a taskill (1 vs 2 k's). Can you clarify which one you are recommending?

Comment: I'm recommending taskkill which exists on Windows XP Professional, Windows Vista and Windows 7.

Answer (score 0):

I'm sure you know you can use Task Manager to close programs... and alternatively you can monitor and shut down processes easily with it's bigger cousin [Process Explorer](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896653).

Comment: Not enough rep do downvote. This is the kill-process answer the OP was *not* looking for.